# How to get an attribute of the children of a Nokogiri nodeset

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to get the w:rsidR value from all of the w:ins and w:del items in the following xml using Nokogiri:

```
<w:document mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 wp14" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:mo="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mac/office/2008/main" xmlns:mv="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mac:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape">
    <w:body>
        <w:p w14:paraId="56037BEC" w14:textId="1188FA30" w:rsidR="001665B3" w:rsidRDefault="008B4AC6">
            <w:r>
                <w:t xml:space="preserve">This is the story of a man who </w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:ins w:author="Mitchell Gould" w:date="2016-09-28T09:15:00Z" w:id="0">
                <w:r w:rsidR="003566BF">
                    <w:t>went</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:ins>
            <w:del w:author="Mitchell Gould" w:date="2016-09-28T09:15:00Z" w:id="1">
                <w:r w:rsidDel="003566BF">
                    <w:delText>goes</w:delText>
                </w:r>
            </w:del>
            <w:r>
                <w:t xml:space="preserve">to the store to </w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:ins w:author="Mitchell Gould" w:date="2016-09-28T09:15:00Z" w:id="2">
                <w:r w:rsidR="003566BF">
                    <w:t>purchase</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:ins>
            ...
        </w:p>
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```

I use Ruby Zip to unzip the Docx file as follows:

```
zip = Zip::File.open("test.docx")
doc = zip.find_entry("word/document.xml")
file = Nokogiri::XML.parse(doc.get_input_stream)
```

So far I have the following:

```
file.xpath('//w:ins').each do |n|
  puts n.children
  puts n.children.attr('w:rsidR')
end
```

Which produces:

```
<w:r w:rsidR="003566BF">
  <w:t>went</w:t>
</w:r>

<w:r w:rsidR="003566BF">
  <w:t>purchase</w:t>
</w:r>

<w:r w:rsidR="008C3761">
  <w:t>replace</w:t>
</w:r>

<w:r w:rsidR="009D3E86">
  <w:t>place</w:t>
</w:r>

<w:r w:rsidR="00F633DF">
  <w:t xml:space="preserve">was </w:t>
</w:r>

<w:r w:rsidR="00D46E57">
  <w:t>was</w:t>
</w:r>

<w:r w:rsidR="00F56399">
  <w:t xml:space="preserve"> sat</w:t>
</w:r>
```

I just can't seem to access the w:rsidR properly. How can I accomplish this?  I'm just starting with Nokogiri and having trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@` to get the value of an attribute:

```
file.xpath('//w:ins/w:r/@w:rsidR|//w:del/w:r/@w:rsidDel').each do |id|
  puts id
end
```

The `w:r` element inside the `w:del` element doesn't have a `w:rsidR` attribute only a `w:rsidDel` attribute.

Comment: Thanks very much yenshirak. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Just like @yenshirak said, there is only `w:rsidDel` in `w:del` tag.

So, I think you can just do this:

```
file.xpath('//w:ins//@w:rsidR|//w:del//@w:rsidDel').map(&:value)
```

to get an array of their values.

If you want to print it, just add `puts` in front of it and remove the `map`, because Nokogiri calls `to_s` on the values.

```
puts file.xpath('//w:ins//@w:rsidR|//w:del//@w:rsidDel')
```

Comment: Thanks adrian. I have up voted your answer as its excellent. I have to accept Yenshirak's as its was first.  Thanks for helping me out.